# jasmine test for spying on click not working

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dom, coffeescript, jasmine

I have been trying to write a test for the following piece of code in angular

```
$scope.openFileWindow = ->
  $timeout ->
    $('#profile-pic-input').trigger 'click'
```

so far I have come with the following piece of code

```
 @timeout = $injector.get '$timeout'
 @windowSpy = spyOnEvent('#profile-pic-input', 'click')
 it 'should open file window', ->
    @scope.openFileWindow()
    @timeout.flush()
    expect(@windowSpy).toHaveBeenTriggered()
```

The problem i am facing is that the @WindowSpy isn't working at all; running the code without @windowSpy and expect(@windowSpy).toHaveBeenTriggered() passes the test

UPDATE: 
       I have modified my code to the one below, and the test passed but is it a valid way to do things ?

```
$('body').append('<div id="profile-pic-input"></div>')
it 'should open file window', ->
@scope.openFileWindow()
@timeout.flush()
@expect(@scope.openFileWindow).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: Shouldn't `expect(windowSpy).toHaveBeenTriggered()` be `expect(@windowSpy).toHaveBeenTriggered()`?

Comment: Is the `$scope.openFileWindow` defined in a controller or somewhere else? Trying to understand the context.

Comment: yup its defined in a controller

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa I tested it with expect(windowSpy) as well and it didn't work. im updating now

Comment: When unit testing controllers there usually is no DOM present. The following selector in your controller function `$('#profile-pic-input')` will not find anything. Same with the selector passed to `spyOnEvent`.

Comment: @tasseKATT please check my updated code and tell me if that is a valid way of doing it ?

Comment: `@expect(@scope.openFileWindow).toBeTruthy()` is checking if the function itself is truthy, which is always true.